# GIS and public health?

Tags: references, training, health

I am starting to research on the topic related to use of GIS in public health. I have started with the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIS_and_public_health).

I would like to apart from epidemic spread of disease, what are the other application areas? Currently active research groups/universities working on these topics? World Health Organization projects? Resources that would help students researching in this area?

Comment: This is good that you have tried to search at least somewhere. As a student you should also try to search libraries or at least try google-scholar. There are plenty (no, there are tons!) of articles about GIS + health. Make some extra effort and search for them yourself. You may start here: http://www.plosone.org/

Answer (score 4):

> Currently active research groups/universities working on these topics?

[Centers for Disease Control and Prevention (CDC)](http://www.cdc.gov/)

> Resources that would help students researching in this area?

[Here](https://www.cdc.gov/gis/gis-training.htm) are two interesting resources: the first one is a GIS training (in ArcGIS) for public health professionals which goes from basics to advanced topics. The second is the .pdf 'Cartographic Guidelines for Public Health' (2012) which *"proposes cartographic guidelines and best practices to produce high-quality, consistent map products for the public health community"*.

Answer (score 3):

Some good reference texts:

- [GIS and Public Health](http://www.guilford.com/cgi-bin/cartscript.cgi?page=pr/cromley.htm&dir=geo/med)
- [Medical
  Geography](http://www.guilford.com/cgi-bin/cartscript.cgi?page=pr/meade.htm&dir=geo/med)
- [Cartographies of
  Disease](http://esripress.esri.com/display/index.cfm?fuseaction=display&websiteID=90&moduleID=0)

Check out the proceedings from the following:

- [Esri's Health GIS conference](http://www.esri.com/events/health/index.html)
- [URISA's Health GIS conference](http://www.urisa.org/conferences/health)

Some other Esri references:

- [Geomedicine](http://www.esri.com/industries/health/geomedicine)
- [GIS for Health Tutorial](http://esripress.esri.com/display/index.cfm?fuseaction=display&websiteID=220&moduleID=0)
- [Spatial Statistics](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/07/13/spatial-statistics-resources/)

And as @SS_Rebelious has commented, there are tons of articles available through internet searches, etc., where often you will find reports/publications like [Exploring the Utilization of Geographic Information Systems in Health Promotion and Public Health](http://www.publichealth.ualberta.ca/research/~/media/publichealth/Research/Research%20Reports/nykiforuk_TR08-001_full_report.ashx), and blogs like [Journals for GIS in Urban and Health Research](http://whowherewhy.wordpress.com/2009/11/13/journals-for-gis-in-urban-and-health-research/) where someone has already compiled similar information that you are looking for.